# DotNetNuke - Restore Backup Issue

Tags: sql-server, dotnetnuke, sql-server-2014

I'm currently having an issue restoring a backup of a DotNetNuke site. I have the .bak file. Using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014, I try to restore the .bak file to a database. However, a message remains at the top of the window: "No backupset selected to be restored." When I attempt to check the contents of the .bak, I receive the following error: "Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types. (mscorlib)"

After doing some research, the most common cause of this error is attempting to restore a newer version of SQL to an older version of SQL. The problem is that I am using SQL Server 2014, so this certainly cannot be the issue. Please help!!!

Comment: you said you are using sql server management studio 2014, but didn't say which version of sql server the backup is from, and which version of sql server you are restoring to.

Comment: I'm not sure what version the backup is from. My friend gave me the .bak file. Is there anyway to check easily? Also I'm not really sure what version DNN would be using.

Comment: It could be that the version the backup is from has a service package you don't have? Can't you ask your friend what version they are running?

Comment: instead of using SSMS GUI to do the restore, use TSQL instead.  The engine should give you a more detailed error message.

Comment: Alright. It turns out Greg was right. I was restoring it to an older version of SQL Server even though I was using management studio 2014. So, I created a 2014 SQL Server instance, and I was able to restore it to that. The problem is that I'm not sure how to access my DNN pages now. :/